# How to export iBooks Author .ipa file to ePub

Tags: epub

iBooks Author 2.5

```
Blank ePub template.
Import file. 
Make corrections.
Save. Now there's a *.ipa file.
The export procedure to create an ePub is supposed to be:
Share>Export>ePub.
```

But ePub is not one of the options.
The options under Share>Export are: iBooks, PDF, Text.
How can I create an ePub file??

Comment: Apple states your template has to support epub in order to have the option to export it as epub: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2809?locale=en_US. Plus, isn't "iBooks" format just epub?

Comment: I used *their* blank ePub template. iBooks have an .iBook extension. If you're suggesting that simply changing the extension from that to .epub is all that's necessary, that would be news indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will do what you want but have you tried using the app Calibre?  This is a free app for managing e-books. I use it at times to create PDF's from different formats. It manages many different formats. I'd suggest trying it and see if it will do what you want.

Comment: Calibre won't read .ipa files. I tried using Calibre on an ePub and the ToC was useless, e.g., a single footnote was treated as a chapter.

Answer (score 0):

In **iBooks Author**, export to **Apple Books** format ("`.ibooks`").

Then, just rename to "`.epub`".

Edit (thx @bmike): This was on Mojave (10.14.3) with Apple Books, but I may have just gotten lucky, Apple's proprietary extensions are unlikely to work and could quite possibly cause error. I'm not sure how commonly used they are, though.

Comment: Which ePub  reader / os version do you use this slight of hand trick on successfully?